# Does Google Calendar send SMS notifications for free?

Tags: google-calendar, sms

I am somewhat new to Google Calendar. What strikes me is that apparently it can send SMS notifications to mobile phones around the world free of charge (or, at least, I don't see any warning text telling me about charges).

This seems strange to me, especially since many network operators around the world still charge quite a lot for SMS services, and in this manner people could very well use Google calendar to send themselves SMS without paying for them. Then again, with all those internet messageing services available nowadays, who would care to use SMS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/45351?hl=en

> Google Calendar is a free product and Google doesn't charge you to receive notifications. Please keep in mind that your mobile service provider's standard rate for receiving text messages may apply. If you have any questions about the rate, please contact your service provider for more information.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The rate of receiving messages from my provider (named WIND in Italy), is basically unlimited SMS from anywhere including abroad and overseas. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Google used to send SMS notifications for free. However, starting on 27 June 2015, Google Calendar will no longer send SMS notifications. Instead, you will only to use pop-up notifications which will display either in an open web browser pointed to the [Google Calendar](http://www.google.com/calendar/) app, or, in Android devices with the Google Calendar app installed, notifications will be pushed by Google to the device, and these will display in a fashion similar to the Alarm app's notifications.